# How can I get and set the caret position in editable div if there is not only text, but also other html nodes in this div (span, div...)?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying **to adjust caret position in editable DIV**, but I can’t do it if **DIV contains other nodes**. Can someone write me how to do this? Thanks a lot.
I can enter text, and I can enter certain characters that will be inserted into this div in some kind of wrapper (span, div and etc), how can I get the caret position if the div contains other nodes?

For example, I typed a few characters and inserted my token (bracket). 
First bracket inserted in span wrapper, but I can't get right position for next one:
[image]

```
<div contenteditable="true">12<span class="with-token">[</span>34[5</div>

***To get:***
const getNodeOffset = node => (node == null ? -1 : 1 + 
getNodeOffset(node.previousSibling));

const getNodeTextLength = (node) => {
let textLength = 0;

if (node.nodeName === 'BR') {
    textLength = 1;
} else if (node.nodeName === '#text') {
    textLength = node.nodeValue.length;
} else if (node.childNodes != null) {
    for (let i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i += 1) {
        textLength += getNodeTextLength(node.childNodes[i]);
    }
}

return textLength;
};

const getTextLength = (parent, node, offset) => {
  let textLength = 0;
  if (node && node.nodeName === '#text') {
    textLength += offset;
} else {
    for (let i = 0; i < offset; i += 1) {
        textLength += getNodeTextLength(node.childNodes[i]);
    }
}

if (node !== parent) {
    textLength += getTextLength(parent, node.parentNode, 
getNodeOffset(node));
}

return textLength;
};

const getTextSelection = (editor) => {
   const selection = window.getSelection();

   if (selection != null && selection.rangeCount > 0) {
      const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
      return {
        start: getTextLength(editor, range.startContainer, 
         range.startOffset),
        end: getTextLength(editor, range.endContainer, range.endOffset)
    };
   } else return null;
};



***To set:***
 function createRange(node, chars, range) {
   let currentRange = range;
   if (!currentRange) {
     currentRange = document.createRange();
     currentRange.selectNode(node);
     currentRange.setStart(node, 0);
   }

   if (chars.count === 0) {
     currentRange.setEnd(node, chars.count);
   } else if (node && chars.count > 0) {
     if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        if (node.textContent.length < chars.count) {
            chars.count -= node.textContent.length;
        } else {
            currentRange.setEnd(node, chars.count);
            chars.count = 0;
        }
    } else {
        for (let lp = 0; lp < node.childNodes.length; lp += 1) {
            currentRange = createRange(node.childNodes[lp], chars, 
   currentRange);

            if (chars.count === 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
return currentRange;}

function setCurrentCursorPosition(node, chars) {
 if (chars >= 0) {
    const selection = window.getSelection();

    const range = createRange(node, { count: chars });

    if (range) {
        range.collapse(false);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you adjust the caret position without additional nodes in the DIV and what exactly is the problem when there the DIV contains additional nodes?

Comment: without any code? please put your code here to give better help.